# How many users have got the updated app version

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have recently pushed a new version of an Android App to the play store, and would like to see how many of our users have managed to get the update already.

There seems to be stats for days on the android version and the devices that are being used, but I cant seem to find anything on what version of the app my users are using.

Comment: To getting the information of version about the application, you have to implement the google analytic. which will give you the detail about the how many user have latest version of your app...

Comment: Developer console provides you with data about how many users have installed the update (rather outdated though - like couple of days old). If you need up-to-date information about the exact amount of people using new version - then it's better to follow @TejaDroid's advice and use google analytic or any kind of other tracking sdk.

Comment: Odd, my developer console shows me version statistics, too. Second to the last button on the Statistics page is "App Version." Is yours different? If you want current information, say on server interactions, just have to app report its version to you with each call.

Comment: what we do is version the api calls, so that we always know how many unique users are hitting the different api routes. this gives us live version data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Go to https://play.google.com/apps/publish/ and login in to your developer account.

Click on the app that you want the information and go to `Statistics` on the left menu.

Now, you have a graph on your page. You can select the type of stats you want to see on the top in the middle, keep "Installs on active devices" selected. Right below that, you have another dropdown on "Android version". You'll want to click that and find one of which says `App Version`. Click there and the second graph will update and show different color for each released version of your app.

[image: Screenshot of the play console]

You can see on the top of the graph the different versions (19, 21, 22). You can hover your mouse on the lines to see the quantity for each app version. There's also the default "All app versions".

The date interval can also be changed on the top to see farther in the past.

---

@edit (Oct/2018)

Updated screenshot for new play console, since this answer keeps getting attention :)

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeR, but this gives me outdated information.. it seems to always be around 3 days behind in the statistics?

Comment: @AaronLeggett, exactly. That's something with Google... You can also see this information through Admob, if you have analytics or ads implemented on your app, but they use the same info from Google Play, so it takes the same delay.

Answer (score 37):

This is how it's done on the Google Play Console as of January 2021.

In `Statistics`, use the 2 dropdown menus below `Configure report` to select:

- `Users > Installed audience`
- `View by: App version`

Unfortunately, there is a significant delay which prevents getting meaningful data during the first DAYS following a new release...
[image]

Surprisingly, Firebase Analytics "Latest Release" dashboard has an even worse delay in its `% of active users` data!

[image]

Comment: Thanks this helped.  Google keeps changing GP Console in ways that make it less obvious how to get such basic data.  Used to be much simpler.

Comment: There is no damn "View by"

Comment: Everything is as you said but I can not find my latest app release version in the "View by: App Version" options. I am relaying on Firebase Console for now

Answer (score 33):

The play console has changed, now you need to go to "Statistics" in the left menu, then click on "configure report", choose "app version" in the right column. Then you have the statistics by app version in the last section of the page.