# How to check how many users have been updated to new version of the app

Tags: android, google-analytics-firebase

I need count of users who have been updated to new version of the android app.
Please let me know how and where to find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010318/how-many-users-have-got-the-updated-app-version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many users have got the updated app version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010318/how-many-users-have-got-the-updated-app-version)